# Detect mode/srclang from selected subtitle track tag in video, or when subtitles are turned off

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, caption

On our site we have video tags, some of which have captions/subtitles in the form of `track` tags inside the main video tag.

Sometimes we would just have one `track` tag, usually with label="English" and srclang="en" but sometimes label="Cymraeg" and srclang="cy".

I want to cookie the user's caption preferences, like so:

- user switches captions off - set cookies['caption_prefs'] to "off"
- user switches "en" captions on - set cookies['caption_prefs'] to "en"
- user switches "cy" captions on - set cookies['caption_prefs'] to "cy"
  etc

But, how can i detect when this happens?  I've got close to it, I think, with a mixture of jquery and plain js:

```
  var video, video_tag, tracks;
  $('video').each(function(){
    video = $(this);
    video_tag = video.get(0);
    tracks = video_tag.textTracks;

    tracks.addEventListener('change', function(event){
      console.log('subtitles changed');
    });
  });
```

This does output 'subtitles changed' when I select a caption. But how can I detect which option the user chose?  Can i do it all with jquery?

**EDIT** - i think i've got it: new change event functionality:

```
    tracks.addEventListener('change', function(event){
      for (let i = 0; i < tracks.length; i++) {
        console.log("subtitles changed: "+tracks[i].language+": "+tracks[i].mode);
      }
    });
```

This now outputs like so:

```
//subtitles turned off
subtitles changed: en: disabled
subtitles changed: cy: disabled

//cy chosen
subtitles changed: en: disabled
subtitles changed: cy: showing
```

This is enough info for me to work out what the cookie should be set to: i just need to find the first track with .mode == "showing" and get its .language value, falling back to 'off' if none of them match.